# Split an HTML structure into an array of tags

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, string

I'm trying to split up an HTML file into an array of tags, the goal being I will then prepend and append ANSI escape codes to color each line according to tag, and then spit to console, and it will be color coded.

I'm able to so far extract each tag one by one with regex (bad idea apparently) and my idea was to then locate the index of that tag and prepend/append the escape codes but the problem I ran into was multiple tags that look the same like two divs next to one another.

**code to loop over tags**

```
var htmlTagRe = /<\/?[\w\s="/.':;#-\/]+>/gi;
const innerHTMLarr = text.match(htmlTagRe).reduce((prev, next) => {
    console.log('prev', prev)
    console.log('next', next)
    console.log()
    return next
});
```

however this only spits out the following and misses self closed tags like `<img />`:

```
prev <html>
next <body>

prev <body>
next <div>

prev <div>
next </div>

prev </div>
next <p>

prev <p>
next </p>

prev </p>
next <p>

prev <p>
next </p>

prev </p>
next <div style="border: 1px solid red">

prev <div style="border: 1px solid red">
next <p>

prev <p>
next </p>

prev </p>
next <span>

prev <span>
next </span>

prev </span>
next </a>

prev </a>
next </div>

prev </div>
next </body>

prev </body>
next </html>
```

**html file**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>text</div>
        <p>a paragraph</p>
        <p>a paragraph</p>
        <div style="border: 1px solid red">
            <p>another one</p><span>test</span>
            <a href="​http://google.com​">
                <img href="​http://site/img.jpg"​ />
            </a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**desired output**

```
[
    '<html>',
    '<body>',
    '<div>text</div>',
    '<p>a paragraph</p>',
    '<p>a paragraph</p>',
    '<div style="border: 1px solid red">',
    '<p>another one</p>',
    '<span>test</span>',
    '<a href="​http://google.com​">',
    '<img href="​http://site/img.jpg"​ />',
    '</a>',
    '</div>',
    '</body>',
    '</html>',
]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @MatthewCliatt I've already seen that thread, it doesn't answer my question. I already know using regex is bad.

Comment: If you've seen the post then you should know that using regex to parse HTML is so bad that you shouldn't post questions about it here. That's why the post is left as is.

Comment: Note that the `<img>` tag does not need or use a closing slash and never has.

Comment: @MatthewCliatt great, still doesn't help me with my question as i have already acknowledged its bad and im looking for an *alternative* solution. you are not helping at all. i'm sorry i posted here.

Comment: @MatthewCliatt actually I solved it with `<(?:"[^"]*"['"]*|'[^']*'['"]*|[^'">])+>(.*?)<(?:"[^"]*"['"]*|'[^']*'['"]*|[^'">])+>|<(?:"[^"]*"['"]*|'[^']*'['"]*|[^'">])+>`. How bout dem apples?

Comment: @eveo `<div><br>poo</div>` as said Regexp can't parse html, it's not about how long and complicated you make the regexp it's about formal grammars.

Comment: worked for me. used an xml parser instead though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery and a recursive function, but you have to escape the symbol " because it apears \".

The result is in the console:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    
    <head>
    <title>Stack Overflow</title>
   <html>
    <body>
        <div>texteeee</div>
        <p>a paragraph</p>
        <p>a paragraph</p>
        <div style="border: 1px solid red">
            <p>another one</p>
   <span>test</span>
            <a href="​http://google.com​">
                <img href="​http://site/img.jpg"​ />
            </a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var result = ['<html>','<body>'];
var lenght = $("body")[0].children.length;

for(var i=0; i< $("body")[0].children.length-1; i++){
 var ele =$("body")[0].children[i];
 if(ele.children.length <= 0 ) {
  var param = '';
  if(ele.attributes.length > 0) 
   param = ele.attributes[0].nodeName+'="'+ele.attributes[0].nodeValue+'"';
   console.log(param);
  result.push('<'+ele.nodeName+ ' ' + param+'>'+
  ele.innerHTML+
  '</'+ele.nodeName+'>');
 }else{
  result.push('<'+ele.nodeName+'>');
  recurs(ele);
  result.push('</'+ele.nodeName+'>');
  }
}

function recurs(ele){
for(var i=0; i< ele.children.length; i++){
 var eleRec=ele.children[i];
 if(eleRec.children.length <= 0 ) {
  var paramRec ='';
  if(ele.attributes.length > 0) 
   paramRec = ele.attributes[0].nodeName+'="'+ele.attributes[0].nodeValue+'"';
  result.push('<'+eleRec.nodeName+ ' ' + paramRec+'>'+
  eleRec.innerHTML+
  '</'+eleRec.nodeName+'>');
 }else{
  result.push('<'+eleRec.nodeName+'>');
  recurs(eleRec);
  result.push('</'+eleRec.nodeName+'>');
  }
 }
}

 
 result.push('<html>');
 result.push('<body>');
 
    console.log(result);
 
});
</script>
    </body>
```

Comment: `[X]HTML` [is not parseable by regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/17300) alone. "HTML is not a regular language and hence cannot be parsed by regular expressions."